# Unity reports an error when packaging an apk file: pick up JAVA_TOOL_options and so on

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

messages:[image: error message]

I tried to I tried changing the file under GrandleTemplates folder.i have already changed the pack name and company name. The icon is changed.

```
**Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven2' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven3' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven4' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'flatDir' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)*

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
   > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details. 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: Check your gradle configuration files and settings files where `http://maven.aliyun.com` is configured and at least change it to https. Better check who operates this server and if you really need it, because this is not a standard repository. Using an untrusted repository may infect your system with malware.